# Does OpenIE extract relations in Spanish?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm trying to use OpenIE for relation extraction in Spanish but it doesn't give any output.

It gives you a triple in English:

[image: It gives you a triple in English]

But it doesn't give any output in Spanish:

[image: But it doesn't give any output in Spanish]

Is there a model to build/train or another way to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no support for Spanish at this time.